# Program a mathematical using recursive function

Tags: c, math, recursion

I want to program the mathematical function `f(x)=sqrt(1^1+sqrt(2^2+sqrt(3^3)+...+sqrt(x^x)))`, where x should be `1 <= x <= 10`. I tried to programm the function like this:

```
double f1Rek(int x)
{ 
   if( x < 1 ) return sqrt(power(x,x));
   return sqrt(power(x,x) + f1Rek(x-1));
}
```

The function power is also a self created recursive function:

```
double power(int x, int n)
{
   if( n == 0 ) return 1.0;
   if( x == 0 ) return 0.0;
   if( exp > 0 )
   {
       return n * power(n, exp - 1);
   }
   if( exp < 0 )
   {
       return 1 / ( n * power(n, -(exp-1));
   }
}
```

The problem is the `f1Rek(int x)` function, because it starts with the `sqrt(x^x + sqrt( x-1^x-1...` . How can I solve the problem in a very elegant way?

Update:

With the answer of Jim Balter, i created a function with 2 Arguments:

```
double f2Rek(int i, int x)
{
   if( i <= x )
   {
      return sqrt(power(i,i) + f2Rek(i+1, x));
   }
   else return 0.0;
}
```

Is there a possibility to define a recursive function with only one argument.

Comment: Are you excited about that ten or is that a factorial?

Comment: Hint: `double f1Rek(int k, int x)`

Comment: What do you mean with the ten? 1 <= x <= 10, do you mean the ten here?

Comment: yeah is it 1 <= x <= 10 or 1 <= x <= 3628800.

Comment: Beta can you explain it a little bit more please?

Comment: These comments are irrelevant. See my answer.

Comment: Is that relevant if 1 <= x <= 10 or 1 <= x <= ... ?

Comment: Why did you ask for a recursive function and then accept an answer that gave an iterative solution instead?

Comment: I'm sorry.. i mixed the "useful" Button with the accepted button. Sure, the answer wasn't recursive...

Comment: But nobody tried the solution with only one argument...

Comment: Can someone help to find a solution with only one argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> f(x)=sqrt(1^1+sqrt(2^2+ **(** sqrt(3^3)+...+ **(** sqrt(x^x))) **)...**

(Assuming what's in bold)

Equivalently,

> f(x) = g(1, x)

where

> g(i, n) = sqrt(i^i + g(i+1, n)) if i <= n, else 0

You should be able to elegantly code your recursive function from that.

In regard to a function with one argument:

f *is* a function with one argument. It calls a recursive helper function that takes two arguments. 
 It's clear that the recursive inner function needs two arguments, one of which is the termination value, x. In a language with local functions that argument can be hoisted out of the function, e.g.,

```
double f(int x)
{
   double g(int i)
   {
       return (i <= x)? sqrt(pow(i, i) + g(i+1)) : 0.0;
   }

   return g(1);
}
```

GCC supports local functions, but they aren't in standard C.

Comment: The first argument of g(1,x) should always the one?

Comment: Look again ... `g(i+1, n)` ... that's not 1. The *initial* first argument is 1, because that's how the series starts. The second argument is always `n` (the x argument of f) because that's the termination value.

Comment: @T.C. *"The first argument of `g(1,x)` should always the one"* Presented like that, how could it be anything else? I *think* you meant `g(i,x)`, and Jim answered that.

Comment: Okay i get it.. it's another solution, but i tried it with only one argument.

Comment: Jim Balter, is the function not possible with only one argument?

Comment: "it's another solution" -- It's the solution. "but i tried it with only one argument" -- Your function computes sqrt(x^x + sqrt((x-1)^(x-1) + ... sqrt(1^1 + sqrt(x^x)))...)) which is quite wrong. Yours only needs 1 argument because your termination value is 0, which is a constant.

Comment: Yes, i know that sqrt(x^x + sqrt((x-1)^(x-1) + ... sqrt(1^1 + sqrt(x^x)))...)) is not the same as sqrt(1^1+sqrt(2^2+sqrt(3^3)+...+sqrt(x^x)))... but i tried to program it, and it doesn't work, thatway i asked here for help..

Answer (score 1):

```
double f1Rek(int x)
{  
   double res = 0.0;
   for(int i=x; i > 0; i--) {
     res = sqrt(power(i,i) + res));
   }
   return res;
}
```

Comment: If all you need is the right results, then it's useful ... and you should change your question. But if you're doing homework that is supposed to help you understand how to write recursive functions then it isn't useful.

Comment: It has nothing to do with homework.. i just try to programm mathematical in C, nothing else.